# Which is better to be used along with Prism4, Unity or MEF as a Dependency Injection Container?

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism, mef, prism-4

I am working on a large billing application for one the Telecom companies using WPF4, the application contains more than 300 screen, and it will contain more than 17 modules, that is why I choose to follow Prism4 guidance.

After a lot of readings about Prism4, I couldn't decide which Dependency Injection container I should use (either MEF or Unity)? they almost have the same capabilities.

I am sure that Microsoft will drop one of them after a while (maybe two or three years) once they converge to each other (and they are almost there) like what happened to LINQ to SQL and EF. What I am afraid of, is to build my solution using one of them and after a while Microsoft drop it!

Moreover, in-terms of capabilities, If you have a working knowledge of both, which one you think is better? and why?

Please help me to decide.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MEF has the advantage of being a part of the core .NET Framework.  It shipped as part of the framework itself in .NET 4.  Unity is still a separate installation, and not the core framework.

As such, if you want to have the longest potential life, MEF is at least "officially supported" as part of .NET.  I would say it has a safer future in that respect.

Answer (score 3):

MEF is a part of the .NET 4 framework and thus will not be dropped.